# Plotting of values using heatmap in Matlab: Wrong output attained

Tags: image, matlab, heatmap

I have a 512*512 matrix which contains calculated probabilities. I am trying to plot the ocuucrences of 0s and 1s of these using a heatmap so that my final image is somewhat like an inverted flattened gaussian function;

the problem is my code returns an image where all values are along the 0 only; this is not possible as I have an almost equal probability of 0s and 1s. Is there some problem with my plotting of the values?

```
X = reshape(prob_to_1,512,512); % prob_to_1 is the matrix of probabilities which 
                                % is reshaped to a 512*512 matrix
colormap('hot');
imagesc(X);
set(gca, 'XTick', [0:0.05:1]*512, 'XTickLabel',[0:0.05:1]) % 10 ticks 
set(gca, 'YTick', [0:0.1:1]*512, 'YTickLabel',[0:0.1:1]*100) % 20 
colorbar('YTickLabel',{'100%','90%','80%','70%','60%','50%','40%','30%','20%','10%','0%'})
```

I have attached an image showing my output. As you can see, the black line which shows the no.of 1s should have been at the extreme right on the x-axes (close to prob of 1).

Any suggestions/ideas?

Thanks![image]

[image]

Comment: I find it hard to understand what you are asking... Could you try to explain it better?

Comment: Hi Luis, I have added a second image for more clarity. As you can see now,this shows the distribution of 0s and 1s according to the number of occurences of 0s and 1s.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the second image is a histogram of the same data. hist(X,nbins) is sufficient for plotting it.